# Where should the period/full stop go in this instance?

Tags: punctuation, periods

In a sentence that ends with a quoted proper name (of a newspaper), where should the "period" go? Currently it is this:

the “Morning Call”.

...but that doesn't look right.

Should it be this:

the “Morning Call.”

...or this:

the *Morning Call*.

Comment: In US English, if quotation marks are used in the text in the question, then the period comes before the closing quotation mark. In UK English, in this construction *specifically*, it goes outside the closing quotation mark. (In other constructions it would also go before.) If the style guide you follow says to use italics with the name of the newspaper (the *Associated Press* does not use italics), then it's obvious.

Comment: See this [answer posted on a different question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/79320/44619)

Answer (score 1):

If the sentence ends with the name of a newspaper, the OP doesn't need to place quotation marks (inverted commas) around the name, italics will do the job quite nicely, and the period (full stop) can be placed at the end, as it should. The name of the newspaper, if it's the Pennsylvania one,  is *[The Morning Call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Morning_Call)*

> …blah, blah, blah *The Morning Call*.

Wikipedia has an article about the newspaper, note it uses italics throughout, never quotation marks for newspaper names.

> The newspaper is owned by Tribune Publishing, whose other publications include the *Chicago Tribune*, *The Baltimore Sun*, *Orlando Sentinel*, *Sun-Sentinel*, *Hartford Courant*, *Daily Press* and *The Virginian-Pilot*.
>   (*Wikipedia*)